# Python and GAE Timezone Conversion

Tags: python, date, time, timezone

Using Django. One of my model has a DateProperty attribute which is set by default as date.today().

The GAE doco states that DateProperty fields are automatically converted to UTC times before being stored. After my object has been stored, i would like to convert back its date to Melbourne time and use that as a string.

The following code is what i'm trying to do:

```
def convert_date(self):
    local = pytz.timezone(TIMEZONE)
    return self.date.astimezone(local)
```

Assuming TIMEZONE = 'Australia/Melbourne'

So far I've been unsuccessful and haven't found any working solution on the internet.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by replacing DateProperty to DateTimeProperty and the following code:

```
def convert_date(self):
    tz = pytz.timezone(TIMEZONE)
    dt = tz.normalize(tz.localize(self.date)).astimezone(tz)
    return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```